# How many private variables is too much?

Tags: python, oop, private-members

I'm currently working on my first larger scale piece of software, and am running into an ugly situation. Most features I have added thus far have required an additional private member in order to function properly. This is due to the fact that most features have been giving more power to the user, by allowing them to modify my program through either arguments passed to the constructor, or methods that specify a setting they wish to toggle.

I currently have around 13 private variables, and can see this spiraling out of control. The constructor code is starting to look very ugly. I was wondering if this is just a result of adding features, or if there was a creative/clever way to avoid this issue.

Comment: Can you show an example of this?

Comment: It sounds like you're designing a [god object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object). Can you split up the functionality into multiple smaller classes?

Comment: there is no such thing as "private variables" in python

Comment: This is a matter of design; 13 private variables by itself isn't too many, but it could be a sign that your class is doing too many things, and could be decomposed into separate class, each of which requires less private state.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Let's pretend he wrote "`_`-prefixed variables intended to be an implementation detail" and move on, shall we?

Comment: hehe :P ok ok i guess i dont need to be pedantic :P

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend abstracting the concept of of "behavior"

You'd have a base class "behavior" which actually performs the requested action, or manages the modification to behavior.  Then you can initialize your code using an array of "parameters" and "behaviors".

Your startup code would become a simple "for" loop, and to add/remove behaviors you just add or remove to the list.

Of course, the *tough* part of this is actually fitting the activities of the behavior classes into your overall program flow.  But I'm guessing that a focus on "single responsibility principle" would help figure that out.

Comment: while this is probably a very good recommendation, I have a hard time seeing how this apply to the question given how little details is provided in the OP.

Comment: Perhaps.  I'd have to admit my answer is quite focused to the last half of the final sentence: "I was wondering ... if there was a creative/clever way to avoid this issue"